# Transfer Visual Studio 2019 theme to Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to transfer (export/import) a Visual Studio 2019 theme to Visual Studio 2022?

I have tried to import the VS2019 theme which I have created several years ago, no success.
I have tried to export/import the settings but the result was negative

I will be very happy if someone shares a working way to do that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Install the Color Theme Designer from the marketplace:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idex.colorthemedesigner2022.

This will provide a new project type (File -> New) called `VS Theme Project`. You can then copy whatever `.vstheme` file you want into the project (after you've removed the file added by the project template). When you build, your theme will be in the `bin` folder and you can install it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if someone else wants to do this. Because there is no way to add a *.vstheme file directly but using the extensions for VS. I have cloned the [Mads Kristensen repository](https://github.com/madskristensen/BlueColorTheme) for one of his themes and placed my own.

1. Install VS2022 extensibility
2. Clone https://github.com/madskristensen/BlueColorTheme
3. Open the project and replace the *.vstheme file with yours
4. Compile the project and go to bin/release and install the extension *.vsix

Answer (score 1):

This guide by Daniel Hardt was easy to follow and worked perfectly.

https://www.hardt.software/convert-old-vstheme-file-from-vs-2019-to-vs-2022/